# How to disable background child highlight in expandable list

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter

I have a pretty long expandable list with lots of children under each group. 
When a group is expanded and I perform scroll action, I see background behind children becomes dark untill scroll stopps.

Does anybody know how to disable this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

Either in *.xml file add

```
android:scrollingCache="false"
```

or in the code add

```
getExpandableListView().setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
```

without doing that, ExpandableList background was changing to dark like all children got background changed to dark. This could be seen when background is of bright color.